# Drawing an array of shapes using Turtle, but only one showing up

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to draw a bunch of squares using Turtle, but only the last one shows up instead of two. (I'm planning to add more, but i'm stuck on this)

```
wall = []
block = turtle.Turtle()
block.shape("square")
block.color("black")
block.penup()
wall.append(block)
wall.append(block)
wall[0].goto(20, 20)
wall[1].goto(40, 40)
```

Please let me know if you need any additional info and thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?

Comment: @norie I'm basically working to add obstacles to the old snake game as a learning exercise.  The code can be found here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-snake-game-using-turtle-in-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created just a single turtle, but then put two references to that one turtle in your list `wall`. You would need to create turtles in a loop to populate `wall` if you want your list to consist of distinct turtles:

```
import turtle

wall = []
for i in range(2):
    block = turtle.Turtle()
    block.shape("square")
    block.color("black")
    block.penup()
    wall.append(block)
wall[0].goto(20, 20)
wall[1].goto(40, 40)
```

should work as expected.

Another approach, is to forget `wall` completely, stick to a single turtle, but have it `stamp` its shape where you want:

```
block = turtle.Turtle()
block.shape("square")
block.color("black")
block.penup()
    
block.goto(20, 20)
block.stamp()
block.goto(40, 40)
block.stamp()
```

which gives the same visual pattern as the first code.

If the intention is to have a wall of blocks, you could do this in a loop:

```
for x in range(-260,280,20):
    block.goto(x, x)
    block.stamp()
```

will draw a diagonal wall of squares across the turtle screen.

Comment: This was very helpful.  I couldn't understand why appending it two times wasn't working.  After looking at the example you provided and tinkering a bit, I realized that duplicating the the top half of the code with each having an append worked. While this is way less efficient, it helped it all come together in my head.